# I'm getting this error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. But I don't know what to do

Tags: reactjs

This is my useEffect Function:

```
    async function getURL() {
      if (Produtos !== null) {
        const prod = [];
        for (const i of Produtos) {
          const ref = firebase.storage().ref(i.nome + '/0.jpg');
          const uri = await ref.getDownloadURL();
          prod.push({
            uri: uri,
          });
        }
        setURL(prod);
      }
    }
    const cleanUp = firestore()
      .collection('Produtos')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const Prod = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          Prod.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
        setProdutos(Prod);
        getURL();
      },);
      return () => {cleanUp();};
  }, [Produtos]);
```

When I leave the page where this function is, I get this error:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

But I'm already unmounting the function.

Comment: Your cleanup function, called when the component is unmounted, does something that results in the state being updated. It's not clear why you think that would fix the problem.

Comment: Your "cleanUp" function should cancel the Firebase query which you're currently calling. Something like Firebase.cancel()

Comment: Ok, but i noticed that the problem is in getURL function, how did i cancel the firebase query?